# Static Member Variable, Qualified Name is Not Allowed

Tags: c++, c++11

I've searched other answer's on SO and feel like I'm following the format correctly, so not sure what Im doing wrong and am at my wits end with this one....

```
class DBwrapper {
    private:
        static std::string DBfile;
        //static char DBfile[];
```

```
#include "DBwrapper.h"
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string DBwrapper::DBfile = "library.db3";
    std::string DBwrapper::DBfile{"library.db3"};
}
```

In VS, I get red squiggles in main.cpp under DBwrapper::DBfile saying "Qualified name is not allowed".
I've tried with char [] as well as const/not const.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the `static` data member at namespace scope, not in a function like `main`:

```
#include "DBwrapper.h"
#include <string>

// Static data members don't have anything to do with functions
// and their scopes, so this must appear here:
std::string DBwrapper::DBfile = "library.db3";

int main()
{
   // Here, you would rather instantiate DBwrapper to work with it
}
```

Comment: Heh. Just figured this out by starting with new files with nothing but that in them. Literally facepalming now. Spent an embarrassingly long time on something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so, basically don't have it IN the int main(){} function. /facepalms

```
#include "DBwrapper.h"
#include <string>

std::string DBwrapper::DBfile = "file";
int main()
{
//....
}
```

Comment: What's the point of copy-pasting lubgr's answer as if it was your own?